# Automatic MD5 column in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We are starting a new project here and as a premise, every row in every table must have a md5 column calculated with the other columns contents, to check if it was modified outside the application (using manual updates or inserts).

There are already any solution for that?

Comment: What if somebody manually updates the hash?

Comment: This hash has a key that only we knows.

Comment: Doesn't mean that they can't maliciously change it to a different value so it looks like something has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Triggers package](https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers) by Nick Strupat. This gives you a possibility to react on every row's inserting/updating. In triggers implementation you can calculate MD5 for the actual data.